# pygame only shows black screen?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I'm new to pygame and Python in general. I looked up other threads that asked similar questions but it seems that they reached different solutions. Please, someone tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

size = (width, height) = (720, 720)

background_color = (0, 255, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("img/pokeball.jpg")
speed = [2, 3]

ballrect = ball.get_rect()

ballrect.move_ip(0, 0)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)

if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
    speed[0] = -speed[0]

if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
    speed[1] = -speed[1]

screen.fill(background_color)
screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: check your indentation. I am pretty sure everything under the while True: is supposed to be in that loop.

Comment: Thank you. Now I wish could delete this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is working with correct indentation ( 4 spaces indentation in any loop (`while`,...) or `if` statement) :

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

size = (width, height) = (720, 720)

background_color = (0, 255, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

ball = pygame.image.load("/absolute_path/pokeball.jpg")
speed = [2, 3]

ballrect = ball.get_rect()

ballrect.move_ip(0, 0)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()

        ballrect = ballrect.move(speed)

        if ballrect.left < 0 or ballrect.right > width:
            speed[0] = -speed[0]

        if ballrect.top < 0 or ballrect.bottom > height:
            speed[1] = -speed[1]

    screen.fill(background_color)
    screen.blit(ball, ballrect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

i also used an absolute path for the ball .jpg